# Spark groupByKey alternative

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, reduce

According to Databricks best practices, Spark `groupByKey` should be avoided as Spark `groupByKey` processing works in a way that the information will be first shuffled across workers and then the processing will occur. [Explanation](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)

So, my question is, what are the alternatives for `groupByKey` in a way that it will return the following in a distributed and fast way?

```
// want this
{"key1": "1", "key1": "2", "key1": "3", "key2": "55", "key2": "66"}
// to become this
{"key1": ["1","2","3"], "key2": ["55","66"]}
```

Seems to me that maybe `aggregateByKey` or `glom` could do it first in the partition (`map`) and then join all the lists together (`reduce`).

Comment: in the same link Here are more functions to prefer over groupByKey:

combineByKey can be used when you are combining elements but your return type differs from your input value type.
foldByKey merges the values for each key using an associative function and a neutral "zero value".

Comment: I think `groupByKey` is the most efficient choice (both time and storage) here. If it OOMs you simply need a larger cluster.

Answer (score 18):

`groupByKey` is fine for the case when we want a "smallish" collection of values per key, as in the question.

### TL;DR

The "do not use" warning on `groupByKey` applies for two general cases:

1) You want to aggregate over the values:

- **DON'T**: `rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(_.sum)`
- **DO**: `rdd.reduceByKey(_ + _)`

In this case, `groupByKey` will waste resouces materializing a collection while what we want is a single element as answer.

2) You want to group very large collections over low cardinality keys:

- **DON'T**: `allFacebookUsersRDD.map(user => (user.likesCats, user)).groupByKey()`
- **JUST DON'T**

In this case, `groupByKey` will potentially result in an OOM error.

`groupByKey` materializes a collection with all values for the same key in one executor. As mentioned, it has memory limitations and therefore, other options are better depending on the case.

All the grouping functions, like [`groupByKey`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/43f50decdd20fafc55913c56ffa30f56040090e4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L462), `aggregateByKey` and `reduceByKey` rely on the base: `combineByKey` and therefore no other alternative will be better for the usecase in the question, they all rely on the same common process.

Comment: So, there is no way to group the values in an array based on the key, each in its own worker and then merge the resulting arrays with the other parts array? My question is for creating, for example, a reverse index where I would have all the words of a page in an array and the key as the url.

Comment: @AdrianoAlmeida yes - `groupByKey` :-) . Read the link I had placed in the answer: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/43f50decdd20fafc55913c56ffa30f56040090e4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L462  There they advice against map-side combiner b/c of memory impact. You could try with `aggregateByKey` if you think your specific usecase would benefit of map-side combine first.

Comment: @massg Does it mean it will also hamper the performance if we use the this query using the CassandraSQLContext Select Column1, max(Column2) from Table_name Group by Column1. If, yes what is the alternative for the to convert it to reduceby

Comment: What is the best way to handle when your reduce operation is not associative?  That is, if I need to groupByKey, sort the grouping, apply a function to the sorted list, I can't use reduceByKey.  Should i use partitionBy + mapPartitions instead of groupByKey + mapValues to avoid OOM errors?  Is there an issue creating a partition per key?

Comment: great answer! very clean