# Apache Spark any benefit in using map of keys, and source data on reducer side instead of groupByKey()?

Tags: apache-spark

In reviewing this question, [Spark groupByKey alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029395/spark-groupbykey-alternative), I find that I have a similar need, but on much larger data set. Good news is that my data per group will fit in memory on the reducer side.

I need to do some processing on each group's data, and write results out. There are may many grouping values.

Input (copied from that question):

```
{"key1": "1", "key1": "2", "key1": "3", "key2": "55", "key2": "66"}
```

Output (copied from that question):

```
{"key1": ["1","2","3"], "key2": ["55","66"]}
```

Since this is very inefficient and forces massive movement of data across, I was thinking if I could use the spark framework to merely map distinct keys to different reducers, and let the reducer side source the data (from a database or whatever) and do it's computation.

In this case, I will be using Spark to just spread the workload and nothing else really. Is this a useful way to do it? Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the data source; in a lot of ways the groupBy logic is just doing the same work that relational databases would be doing either when building indexes or at query time.

The reason the full shuffle of records is most common in spark and hadoop is that usually these systems are used to deal with exactly the case where the data is not amenable to being well organized in preprocessing, either because the data is too large or because it arrives in unsorted forms (like log files from lots of different server sources) where it's not accessed frequently enough to justify continuous preprocessing.

So in general, if your source data is already efficiently organized by the groupings you need, either because the grouping key is a primary key in your database source or they're otherwise already grouped that way in source files, you can indeed do much better by only pulling in the record values inside reducers, because your storage format has effectively already performed the shuffle operation.

However if the data is not already indexed by your grouping key or it's scattered through unsorted files, it will overall be inefficient trying to pull in the data by key in the reducers because then each time you try to fetch all data of a single key, the underlying storage layer or the reader has to scan through the full set of data that may contain those keys, effectively multiplying the number of data accesses by the number of keys you have.

Even if the data has an index, if the record value requires extra disk seeks to get to it, it could still be well worth it to pay the cost of the extra data shuffle simply because sequential disk access can get orders of magnitude higher throughput than random accesses.

The main takeaway is that the data shuffle is optimized for being able yo organize your data into grouping in more or less a single pass, while filtering by keys is multipass unless efficiently indexed. So shuffle cost is a tradeoff of cost in the source storage layer.

Comment: Great....validates my thinking about not moving the data unnecessarily. In my use case, it seems like Spark and map tasks in particular are simply partitioning 'work' (assigning keys) to different reducers and that is it. Is this type of use case normal? Of course, I can write code to 'allocate' keys to different compute nodes to work on, but seems like Spark mappers can do that just as easily. Is this a useful way to use Spark?

Comment: Yeah, while it can be debatable whether using Spark is overkill for some basic parallelizable tasks, it's definitely a common pattern to use it as a handy framework for mostly dealing with the control plane of parallelization; the same is true for Hadoop as well. If not using the shuffle capabilities, you're still benefiting from the fault tolerance, getting logs from workers, automatic retry of failed tasks, making sure work is evenly distributed to different nodes even as you add/remove nodes, etc.