# Spark group by with custom logic performance

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have parquet files located on HDFS, which contain records of the following form:

```
unique_id_1 | state_1| prop1| prop2 | prop3
unique_id_1 | state_2| prop4| prop5 | prop6
unique_id_1 | state_3| prop8| prop8 | prop9 
unique_id_2 | state_1| prop1| prop2 | prop3
unique_id_2 | state_2| prop4| prop5 | prop6
unique_id_2 | state_3| prop7| prop8 | prop9
```

Each unique_id_x record is present exactly 3 times, with 3 individual states for each unique key, and different other properties.

What I need to do is group all the records by the unique_id, and merge the properties in each group - creating a brand new record which will be written output parquet files.

I have looked into Spark's RDD **groupby** and then **mapValues** - which gives me an Iterable of the 3 rows with the 3 different states - and I can construct my new row just fine.

But I have seen a lot of advice against using the **rdd.groupBy().mapValues()** approach, because of performance reasons - it needs to shuffle a lot of the data(those 3 records need to end up in the same reducer), and it doesn't use a combiner local to a partition to reduce the data.

Other approached listed [here](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/956/how-do-i-group-my-dataset-by-a-key-or-combination.html) suggest the usage of aggregate or groupByKey - but this seems to work if you just have a simple sum() or count() aggregation function - and not some custom logic like I need.

Is there a better way than the current groupBy I have to achieve my end result?

EDIT: I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029395/spark-groupbykey-alternative) answer about group by: "groupByKey is fine for the case when we want a "smallish" collection of values per key, as in the question." Given my situation where I always have 3 values per key - would this approach be the best one suited for this case?

EDIT 2: Attaching code:

```
SQLContext sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sparkContext.sc());

    JavaRDD<MyBean> rdd = sqlContext
            .read()
            .parquet(inputLocation)
            .toJavaRDD()
            .groupBy((Function<Row, String>) v1 -> v1.getAs("record_id"))
            .mapValues((Function<Iterable<Row>, MyBean>) records -> {
            //getting the 3 states from the interator and merging them
                Supplier<Stream<Row>> rowSupplier = () -> StreamSupport.stream(records.spliterator(), false);
                Optional<Row> state1Row = rowSupplier.get().filter(row -> row.getAs("state").equals("state_1")).findFirst();
                Optional<Row> state2Row = rowSupplier.get().filter(row -> row.getAs("state").equals("state_2")).findFirst();
                Optional<Row> state3Row = rowSupplier.get().filter(row -> row.getAs("state").equals("state_3")).findFirst();

                return merge(state1Row, state2Row, state3Row); //contains the merge logic - returns an instance of MyBean

            })
            .map((Function<Tuple2<String, MyBean>, MyBean>) Tuple2::_2); //not interested in the record_id anymore
     sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, MyBean.class).write().parquet(outputLocation);
```

Comment: Seems like you can do a `reduceByKey` then `mapValues` or `groupby`.

Comment: Could you post an example which works on the input data I have provided? I am finding it difficult to find how to put my custom merging logic inside any reduce function . It doesn't seem to give me the full list of values as an Iterable, like with group by.

Comment: Maybe you can post what you have tried and I can add to it.

Comment: Attached sample code.